# Role of auxin and cytokinins in vascular cambium or callus formation

Tags: botany, endocrinology

Usually, auxins promote cell growth and cytokinins promote cell division. But, I got an information from my teacher that, in case of vascular cambium or callus formation, auxins promote cell division and cytokinins promote cell growth. Is this 'information' true? If true, why?